# Display results from solr with JSP

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsp, struts, solr

I am trying to work out the best way to display solr results in JSP.

I am a bit new to JSP but it seems as if there are a whole bunch of ways of doing it

e.g. Hibernate, Spring MVC, JSP page itself, struts.

It would be great to find out if anyone has any experience with consuming Solr or XML and which of the above solutions is the most simple.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Ke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *whatever* view technology you like.

Hibernate is **not** a view technology, so you can't display anything with it.

Struts and Spring MVC actually use JSP for their presentation layer.

To answer the explicit question: the plain JSP is most simple.